# How does the render performance of Magicavoxel objects compare to standard Cube objects?

Tags: unity

What would be easier to render by the computer:-
1) an obj made in magicavoxel of 50*100*1.
2)an cube in unity with same dimensions with any material or an png image.

Comment: Have you tried making either version? Did you spot any problems with the thing you tried?

Comment: "Any material" is quite vague. A supercomplex pixel shader can suck up quite a lot of GPU cycles, even with simple geometry.

Answer (score 1):

A Cube will have less tris and will be rendered in one draw call